# Adding Table Rows on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to add `table rows` as the user clicks the `Add button`. In a new row there are 3 textboxes. As the rows gets added `id` of textboxes should be set like `array list`.

For e.g
if it is 2nd row added, the textbox `ids` will be `textbox1_1` `textbox2_1` `textbox3_1`
if it is 3rd row added, the textbox `ids` will be `textbox1_2` `textbox2_2` `textbox3_2`

Because I want to Add all these `textboxes` values in a `single string` at the end.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x7yvLrnk/)

Added later :-
Indeed at the first time there are no rows in the table.

Comment: Add your code, here in SO with your question not at fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function(){
    var id = $('table tr').size(),
    i,
    row = '<tr>';

    for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
       row +=  '<td><input type="text" id="text'+i+'_'+id+'" />';
    }   
    row += '</tr>';

    $('table').append(row);
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hypzo/x7yvLrnk/11/)***
Alternativly if you want to build from previous rows you can do this:

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function(){
    var id = $('table tr').size(),
    tr = $('table tr').last().clone();
    $(tr).find('td').each(function (index) {
        $(this).attr('id', 'text'+index+'_'+id);
    });
     $('table').append(tr);
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hypzo/x7yvLrnk/8/)***

Comment: Thanks for the answer..But at the first time i have only empty table...After clicking Add one new row gets added.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : you can add row by cloning first row and updating each `input`'s id by iterating them.

```
//get the count of available row in table
var count = $('#dynamicTable tr').length;

$("#btnAdd").click(function(){
    //clone the first row in table
    var $tr = $('#dynamicTable tr:first').clone();
    //iterate each input to change its id
    $tr.find('input').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.substring(0,id.length-1);
        $(this).attr('id',id+count);
    });

   // update count
    count++;
   //add row to the table
    $('#dynamicTable').append($tr);
});
```

**[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/x7yvLrnk/3/)**

Comment: What changes to make if table is empty at first?

Comment: for empty table, you have to follow the first solution provided by @AndrianForsius.

Answer (score 0):

Try thus

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function(){
    var rowCount = $("table tr").length;
    var firstRow = $("table tr:first").clone();
    firstRow.find("input").each(function(){
        this.id=this.id.replace("_0","_"+rowCount);
    });
    $("table").append(firstRow);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fewzfnzq/)

Answer (score 0):

write less do more with jquery. use chaining as below

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function(){
    $('table')
    .find("tr:first") // traverse the first tr
    .clone() // clone the row
    .appendTo('table') // append the the table tag
    .end() // reset to default selector
    .find('input').each(function(i,x){
      $(this).prop('id',this.id.split('_')[0]+'_'+(+$('table tr').length-1)); // assign the id to the added new row
    });
});
```

**EDIT** done with [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x7yvLrnk/9/) too
Hope it helps....